# How can I factor this jQuery and not repeat myself?

Tags: jquery

I have three layers, two of which are hidden using CSS. I would like to make those layers visible/invisible depending on which input the user focuses on:

The three I'm changing are layers are: #titleBox, #phoneBox, #addressBox, the inputs are #title, #phone, #address. The #titleBox is the only one visible on page load.

```
$("#title").focus(function () {
    $("#phoneBox,#addressBox").hide();
    $("#titleBox").fadeIn("slow");
});
$("#phone").click(function () {
    $("#addressBox,#titleBox").hide();
    $("#phoneBox").fadeIn("slow");
});
$("#address").click(function () {
    $("#titleBox,#phoneBox").hide();
    $("#addressBox").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will cache the "Box" elements, then pull the ID from the ones with the event, and `.hide()` or `.fadeIn()` the proper one using jQuery's [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) methods.

Since you're using 2 different events, I've created a function that can be reused for both.

### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/besMe/

```
// cache the boxes
var $boxes = $('#titleBox,#phoneBox,#addressBox');

// create reusable function that can be applied as click and focus handlers
function boxSwitch( e ) {
    $boxes.not('#' + this.id + 'Box').hide();
    $boxes.filter('#' + this.id + 'Box').fadeIn('slow');
}

// apply the handler
$("#title").focus(boxSwitch);
$("#phone,#address").click(boxSwitch);
```

---

**EDIT:** Corrected mistake. Should have had `.filter()` instead of `.is()`.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for that... It seems to work, but after a while evrything disappears and i get this: boxes.is("#" + this.id + "Box").fadeIn is not a function
[Break on this error] $boxes.is('#' + this.id + 'Box').fadeIn('slow');

Comment: @Mel - Sorry, just updated. I should have had `.filter()` instead of `.is()`. Fixed. This will be quite efficient since it caches the elements, and just filters the one(s) you want.

Comment: @Mel - Also, your question uses 2 different event types, `click` and `focus`. Is that what you intended? If not, this can be simplified a little more.

Comment: @patrick, no, it's only intended to function on focus, not click! But that's easy right? All I have to do is remove the click function and add the ids to the focus function!

Comment: @Mel - Exactly. :o) In which case you could also eliminate the named function, and just use an anonymous function. `$("#phone,#address,#title").focus(function() { $boxes.not(...`

Answer (score 4):

The first piece of jQuery (below) **doesn't work**, but I'm leaving it as evidence of my own idiocy, the stuff after the `<hr />` does, however, work.

```
$("#containerElement input").focus(function () {
    $(div:not'(#'+ this.id '+Box)').hide();
    $('#' + this.id + 'Box').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

---

**Edited:**

Because, basically, the above didn't really work that well. The following, however, does:

#### html:

```
<div id="containerElement">
    <input type="text" id="address" />
    <input type="text" id="phone" />
    <input type="text" id="title" />
</div>

<div id="otherContainer">
    <div id="addressBox">addressBox</div>
    <div id="phoneBox">phoneBox</div>
    <div id="titleBox">titleBox</div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#containerElement input").focus(function () {
            var showThis = this.id + 'Box';
            $(this).val(showThis);
            $('#otherContainer div:not(#' + showThis + ')').hide();
            $('#'+showThis).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/paDj2/).

Comment: Thanks, David! I'm getting this error though: missing ) after argument list
[Break on this error] $(div:not'(#'+ this.id '+Box)').hide();\n

Comment: Yeah, I um...didn't test the jQuery before posting it. Then I went to put the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/paDj2/) together and realised the problems that were there. I've edited to update the answer (with a working demo)...Sorry =/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.input-class-selector').bind('focus', function (event) {

    var el = $('#' + $(this).attr('id'));

    if (!$(el).is(':hidden')) {

       $('.layers-class-selector').hide();
       $(el).fadeIn('slow');

    }

});
```